# Why may we plug in the fee field solution in QFT pertubation theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Assume we would have a free boson field obeying the usual Klein Gorden equation

$$ \frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu \phi \partial^{\mu} \phi - \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 = 0 $$

with as solutions the usual free fields

$$ \int dk \space a_k e^{-ikx} + a_k^t e^{ikx} $$

Now if we add a perturbation to obtain for example $\phi^4$ theory we would be left with a lagrangian equation as follows

$$ \frac{1}{2} \partial_\mu \phi \partial^{\mu} \phi - \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 - \phi^4= 0 $$

The old solution for $\phi$ is at this point no longer a correct solution. However if I follow the procedure in textbooks to find the scattering amplitude of a transition of an initial state $\mid i >$ to $\mid f >$ I find

$$ \int dx <f \mid \phi(x)^4 \mid i> $$

Where we just plug in the old solution for $\phi$
$$ \int dx <0 \mid a_f \bigl(\int dk \space a_k e^{-ikx} + a_k^t e^{ikx} \bigl)^4 a_i^t\mid 0> $$

Why can I use the old (no longer valid) free fields for this? I guess it is OK as I'm dealing with an approximation. But why may I approximate with a free field here?

Comment: It’s because these calculations are done in interaction picture, not Heisenberg picture.

Comment: Of course you are right! Sorry I have been looking at this problem in the wrong way the last 48 hours.... Thanks!